# Bash redirect and append to non-existent file/directory

Tags: bash, redirect

When I use `>> nonexistent/file.log`. Bash gives me back "No such file or directory".

How can I make a one liner that redirects the STDOUT/STDERR to a log file, even if it doesn't exist? If it doesn't exist, it must create the necessary folders and files.

Comment: It should create the files for you automatically. If you want directories too, you'll probably have to just use `mkdir -p`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using `install` :

```
command | install -D /dev/stdin nonexistent/file.log
```

or use

```
mkdir nonexistent
```

first.

Comment: This is a very nice solution! The `/dev/stdin` is really quite useful for a number of commands that only read from disk files but you want it to read from a pipe.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for macOS?  The flag -D does not seem to exist and -d gives two errors "install: /dev/stdin exists but is not a directory" and "(23) Failed writing body"

Answer (score 6):

You can use `dirname` to get the base path of the file, and later use it with `mkdir -p`. After that you can do the redirection:

`` sh
    mkdir -p `dirname nonexistent/file.log`
    echo blah >> nonexistent/file.log ``

Answer (score 3):

If this is run multiple times, and only the first time will the directory be missing, might want to check for it first (before you start your expect stuff)

```
if [ ! -d ~/nonexistent ]
  then mkdir ~/nonexistent
fi
```

Then use the other examples posted to simply scp the resulting file you create with `ls` back to your host box in the newly created directory.

Comment: What's the -d? It doesn't look like a command? I'm guessing it detects non existent directories/files, but why does it work?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  The "-d" checks if a directory exists.  "-e" could also be used ("if exists") but "-d" looks specifically for a directory.  If there was a file by that name it "-e" would incorrectly evaluate true.

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-check-if-file-exists/ has a good tutorial on this.

Comment: no need to script. `mkdir -p` does that check for you

Answer (score 2):

To automatically generate all the directories for a filepath:

```
FILEPATH="/folder1/folder2/myfile.txt"
if [ ! -f "$FILEPATH" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$FILEPATH"
    rm -r "$FILEPATH"
fi
#/folder1/folder2 has now been created.
```